# Why does HttpContext.Response.Cookies["foo"] add a cookie?

Tags: asp.net

I have just spent half a day tracking down a bug due to the following behaviour: -

Imagine that there is **not** a cookie called "foo" in either the Http request's or response's cookie collections.  The following code returns null

```
A) HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["foo"]
```

The following code creates a new cookie called "foo" (with path="/" and blank value), adds it to the response's cookie collection and returns that

```
B) HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["foo"]
```

So (B) has the side effect that any pre-existing cookie called "foo" is overwritten on the client's browser.

This is not a bug.  Someone actually coded this deliberately. Here is the disassembly of the Get method (the Item[string name] indexer delegates to this method.

```
    public HttpCookie Get(String name) {
        HttpCookie cookie = (HttpCookie)BaseGet(name); 

        if (cookie == null && _response != null) { 
            // response cookies are created on demand 
            cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
            AddCookie(cookie, true); 
            _response.OnCookieAdd(cookie);
        }

        return cookie; 
    }
```

Obviously the MSDN docs do not mention this behaviour (although some users have added comments at the bottom of the docs that describe this behaviour).

My question is can someone explain to me the rational why the `HttpCookieCollection` class has this behaviour.

Comment: And why does adding a cookie to Response.Cookies also add the cookie to Request.Cookies - gotta love those side effects.

Comment: I know this is an old issue. The above sounds like Response.Cookies("a.certain.name") and Request.Cookies("a.certain.name") are the same cookie by name. Why wouldn't they be? Hence, if cookies.Get("a.certain.name") or cookies["a.certain.name"] or Request.Cookies("a.certain.name") didn't exist, the only way the Http module to talk to the app is to create it thru the Response.Cookies("a.certain.name") and set it to the new information so the app can request it. It's the coder's job to check if the cookie name being taken or not. Correct? - gotta luv that strange overwriting behaviour :)

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN doc about HttpCookieCollection.Get method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezy11xy2.aspx

> If the named cookie does not exist, this method creates a new cookie
>   with that name.

So yes, this is done on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why? At a guess because it makes sense. If you're doing anything with the response the typical use case is that you want things to be sent to the browser.

You check for values inbound (Request.Cookies) and then you set them outbound (Response.Cookies). The Request is a READ, the Response is a WRITE.

Comment: I agree that it may be the typical use case that you are writing to the response's cookie collection.  But it is very bad API design that a method called "Get" on a collection class changes behaviour between (what I would consider) typical Get behaviour and GetOrCreate behaviour based upon the origin of the items in the collection - would you not agree?

Comment: No, because you can then go Cookies["NewCookie"] = "new value"

Comment: [PS. Your code snippet, as written would not work: the getter returns a HttpCookie (there is no setter) so you  you would have to write Cookies["NewCookie"].Value = "new value"].  I can appreciate that your example reads nicer than Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("NewCookie", "new value")).  If this the only reason for the code behaving as it does, then I personally think that the cons outway the pros.  A SetCookie(string name, string value) method on HttpCookieCollection would have allowed a simple way to add cookies (like in your snippet) without introducing the inconsistent behaviour

Comment: This should be a BUG. It's not intuitive, it's not included in .dll documentation. And when doing async Request.Cookies will be older than Response.Cookies if you access cookie in same request.